# Why is this ReactJS import structure not working?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently developing a React project with the AirBnb React Style guide (https://airbnb.io/javascript/react/)

The project is structured like this (as they advise in the first chapter somewhere):

```
src/
|- components/
|  |- Footer/
|  |  |- index.jsx
|  |- Navbar/
|  |  |- index.jsx
|  |- index.js
|- containers/
|  |- Layout/
|  |  |- index.jsx
```

My navbar looks like this:

```js
// File: src/components/Navbar/index.jsx
import React from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
  return <h1>Navbar</h1>;
}
```

And my footer the same, but instead of `Navbar` its says `Footer` everywhere.

However, I don't want to import the components like this:

```js
// File: src/containers/Layout/index.jsx
import Footer from '../../components/Footer';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
```

But I would like to import them like this:

```js
import { Footer, Navbar } from '../../components';
```

So I tried making an `index.js` file in the components folder with the following contents:

```js
import Footer from './Footer';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export default { Footer, Navbar };
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/containers/Layout/index.jsx
Attempted import error: 'Footer' is not exported from '../../components'.
```

Why does this happen? I've tried using alternatives like:
**Alternative 1**

```js
export { default as Footer } from './Footer';
export { default as Navbar } from './Navbar';
```

But this gives me the same error, I've also tried `import * as Footer from './Footer';` and then export that again, but without success..

---

**Edit:**

After some feedback, this is my footer file:

```js
// src/components/Footer/index.jsx
import React from 'react';

export default function Footer() {
  return <h1>Footer</h1>;
}
```

And I now export it like this:

```
// src/components/index.js
import Footer from './Footer';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export { Footer, Navbar };
```

When I import them like this:

```
// src/containrs/Layout/index.js
import { Navbar, Footer } from '../../components';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

---

**Solution**: My export was wrong and my ReactJS was not refreshing properly (CLI bug I guess? Files were cached..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `export` one default const.

in your `index.js` change to

```
export { Footer, Navbar };
```

Comment: I now have this in my `components/index.js``
```import Footer from './Footer';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export { Footer, Navbar };
```

but I get this error now: 
```Failed to compile.

src\containers\Layout\index.jsx
  Line 4:10:  Footer not found in '../../components'  import/named

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Can you show your Footer (index.jsx) file?

Comment: It works all of a sudden after restarting it two times, I think it was cache because the react cli was not refreshing properly

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the components from a single file firstly you will have to import them in the index.js file like:

#### components/index.js

```
import Footer from './Footer';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export {
   Navbar 
   Footer 
}
```

Then you can import the components like:

#### App.js

```
import { Footer, Navbar } from '../../components';
```